# Village with no boys

Tags: knowledge, real

This is a true story. There is a [Polish village](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/06/world/europe/poland-village-girls-no-boys.html) with no boys born in the last 10 years. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't help thinking you're looking for more than this, but:

From the linked article

> There have only been 12 births during that time

If you simply assume the odds of a boy or girl being born are 50:50, then

> The odds of 12 in a row being girls are only 4096 to 1. That's pretty much bound to happen regularly somewhere in the world, this just happened to attract news coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the `lateral thinking` tag...

> Modelize our problem with $n$ births with proba $\frac12$ for a boy, we might be quite lucky, or unlucky...
>  $$\dfrac1{2^n}$$
>  [image]

Answer (score 0):

> The village has no medical facilities within its boundaries, so any birth *in* the village is a "home birth". If most pregnancies of village residents go to a nearby city for the actual birth, the few "home births" might all happen to have been girls.